# Cannot load webpage on one particular computer

Tags: macos

I have a computer running OS X 10.6.8. One particular webpage will not load regardless of browser or network. Here are the symptoms:

- The website does not load when the URL is entered into any browser. On Firefox, the error is usually "Connection timed out" but sometimes it is "Unable to connect"
- Changing the DNS server does nothing.
- DNS is resolving the correct address for the page. I checked this with nslookup and compared it to a machine which can successfully load the page.
- Cannot ping the site without timing out
- Flushing the cache in the browser does nothing
- Flushing the cache with dscacheutil does nothing
- Clearing browser cookies does nothing
- I can access the page just fine on other devices connected to the same network
- The webpage does not load regardless of network on the victim machine. I tried using my phone's hotspot and the page still does not load on the victim computer. The page loads just fine on my phone.
- No proxy is being used
- Using a VPN **DOES** fix the problem
- /etc/hosts is stock
- I did a scan for malware using clamXav. Nothing turned up except for a couple false positives
- Rebooting does not fix the problem
- Booting into safemode **DOES** fix the problem, but the problem then recurs after booting normally again

I'm really at a loss here. This just started up recently, and I can't recall any change which would have precipitated it.

Comment: how weird... I assume you've tried clearing cache and cookies? What about using incognito/private browsing? Have you tried a USB OS on the same computer?

Comment: Clearing cache and cookies or using private browsing does nothing on any browser. Haven't tried booting a different OS on the machine, that's a good suggestion. Will try that.

Comment: @user2601195 Does it work in Safe mode ? And this machine is not connected to any Corporate network where legacy OS's are blocked over network ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like It works in safemode! But then it continues to not work when booting normally again. The machine is connected to a residential network which I do not administrate, I do not think the OS is being blocked.

Comment: This fact: `Booting into safemode DOES fix the problem` tells me that you have some sort of misconfiguration or setting, or malware (your antivirus could miss it) that interferes with this particular page. While using safemode your system does not boot/load/launch it, so that you can load the page. What sort of web page is this? Can you tell us URL?

Comment: @VL-80 see the answer below. The page in question is azlyrics.com if that helps in figuring out _why_ the solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page would load when I booted in safe mode, I had a hunch it was some software which was being started on log-in. So, I uninstalled LogMeIn Hamachi (which I was not using and was even open at any time) and now I can load the webpage. Weird.

I'm definitely interested on theories why that piece of software would produce those symptoms. I'm more interested on why the problem only just started, since LogMeIn has been installed for years and I haven't run it or updated it in a very long time.

Comment: Might be a network adapter priority problem, I've experienced something similiar with Hamachi on Windows 7. The use of a VPN might change priorities to make things work again. But if this is the problem, then I would expect it to apply to all web sites, not just one.